# Is it possible to define an interface/type to which excess property checks are always applied?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, excess property checks are applied to object literals, but not beyond that. (This is intentional [documented behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).) So given:

```
interface Example {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
// ...
function doSomething(ex: Example) {
    // ...
}
```

This fails ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwCgBIYAEwC5kQBXLAI2gG4yRsIaBnMKUAOZsAvsQD0Y5ADoZxGHRAIwwAPYhkFFQGUVWCGAAWggBQR0NDNnwQAlMhKko+ulHUADACSEzUysJpePhx6wm4ixMSaOnqGJg6UNAAsAEwANOycNABEADLAMBCpyIYoAKogwABu0NyFyHAgFGjVUACesSACWemkZnxw2SAqYPV4eCoA7hAUWcgSaFBQKlDIyQDMiQCsNADyjABWEErIeMCQUHB4yFhwrchqeHfcOEf5dwDWQxPqOEsvUMoINwig0mgByPoXMEaFRA2jDZBmYC8ZCgYqtF7IMGWXAEMFSYjCGxsIA)):

```
doSomething({
    id: 42,
    name: "Life, the Universe, and Everything",
    extra: "not allowed" // Error 2345: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extra' does not exist in type 'Example'.
});
```

but this doesn't ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=22&pln=13&pc=133#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbFAbwCgBIYAEwC5kQBXLAI2gG4yRsIaBnMKUAOZsAvsQD0Y5ADoZxGHRAIwwAPYhkFFQGUVWCGAAWggBQR0NDNnwQAlMhKko+ulHUADACSEzUysJpePhx6wm4ixMQIarzIZsgAvPZklDQALABMADTsnDQARAAywDAQmciGKACqIMAAbtDcpchwIBRo9VAAnoaCedmkZnxw+SAqYM14eCoA7hAUecTCbJo6ej0gAqboNmxAA)):

```
const ex = {
    id: 42,
    name: "Life, the Universe, and Everything",
    extra: "not allowed"
};
doSomething(ex);
```

Is it possible to define the interface in some way that excess properties are forbidden even when not using an object literal? E.g., a "`final`" interface of sorts?

If not, it's easily done at runtime, but if there's a way to do it in the type definition, that would be useful.

Comment: I am very surprised that extracting the object literal to a variable bypasses the excess check. This...seems like a huge oversight. I'm not sure if it's on part of TS or I'm overlooking something but I wouldn't have thought that the two should be treated differently, considering they both get the same implicit interface. EDIT: it *is* mentioned in the documentation, though, so...dunno.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yes, it's an intentional decision of the TypeScript team, a pragmatic compromise. Usually, a type that satisfies another type is fine (even if there are extra bits), but they think that's likely to be an error if you're supplying an object literal, so they apply checks there but document how to get around them if you want the excess properties.

Comment: I understand the decision but extracting the options to a variable is a common refactoring. If you only pass around 1-3 options, then an object literal seems fine but with more than those, it becomes cumbersome to write out every time. Hence why I think there is an oversight. You should really be able to opt into excessive property checks, like you ask for, because maybe you *don't* want to pass in `{ area: number; colour: string; }`. At any rate, I wonder if it's possible to use a mapped type for this - make all other properties `never`, or something.

Comment: Related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is exact types. This feature has been in discussion since forever on [GH](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) but it has not come any closer to actually being implemented. The concern is (at least from what I heard at tsConf from Anders) is that exact types would create a bifurcated type system, where you could not assign from exact to inexact types and backwards, and this would make the dev experience much worse.

There are work arounds, but all are flawed in some way, you can read the GH issue to find all sorts of versions that might work well enough depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, **that** was the search term that would have found it. I searched for "final" and "prevent extending" and such. Thanks!