# Why are some parts of typescript type analysis inconsistent?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface X {
    a: number;
}

const x: X = {
    a: 9,
    // somethingElse: 8 // This would result in compilation error as expected
};

const y = {
    a: 9,
    somethingElse: 8
};

const xx: X = y; // but this works
```

However, I would expect the same behavior as the first assignment, resulting in compilation error because of the extra property.

Comment: The reason is that the extra property doesn't hurt. It's ignored - after all the compiler knows that `xx` is of type `X` and it would stop you using`xx.somethingElse`.

Comment: If you would say that `y` is explicitly of type `X`, the compiler wouldn't let you do it. But this way, the compiler infers, the type of `y` and let you assign it to `xx` as it is a subset of `typeof y`

Comment: Behaviour is documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to [opt into excess property checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929016/is-it-possible-to-define-an-interface-type-to-which-excess-property-checks-are-a). Apparently it is called "exact types" but is not implemented in TS.

Comment: It's a shame one cannot opt in excess property checks, or better, that it was the default but one could opt out. Contrary to what the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929016/is-it-possible-to-define-an-interface-type-to-which-excess-property-checks-are-a#answers-header) suggests, the worst dev experience is this inconsistency, especially down the road working with generics.  
It makes me think of C++ `const`, it's totally fine to only be able to assign one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale I understand is this way :

## Strong restriction when assigning object litteral

When defining directly your `x: X`, the additional property `somethingElse` should *never* be accessed, that seem to be the intent when typing this as `X`.

All along in the rest of the code `x` will always be of type `X` and it does not expose `somethingElse`, so, for the compiler, here it's the code (or the developer ;) ) that is inconsistent.

## Less restriction when assigning from other variable

When you assign the other varriable `xx` with `y`, `y` was not explicitly typed, and thus the property `somethingElse` could still be used in other places.

For the compiler, you seem to temporarily *restrict* `y` to the part that matches the interface `X`, and that's nice. In a more complicated example maybe many different objects could fit this role, so the specific interface typing for `xx` is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: The restriction in object literals works as expected, no developer inconsistencies.

As for the variable assignment, this "temporary restriction" might be sometimes unintended. The compiler shouldn't assume it. Even specifically typing `y: {
    a: number;
    somethingElse: number;
}`, still works, which is inconsistent.

Comment: I think that's the idea of "interface" here, which is really like other programming language. In some situation, you have different complex objects, and a piece of code in your program could acccept any of those objects because they expose a common methods / properties needed to perform the job. Personnally, when I see a parameter which is typed with an interface, I expect that I can pass any complex object, as soon as it fullfills the "interface contract". I suspect that is the philosophy of TypeScript here.

Comment: Of course, it indeed can looks inconsistent, with the point of view you exposed in your question (see other comments on question + github discussion)