# Enforce strict type compatibility on assignments in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Let's consider this chunk of TypeScript code:

```
interface A {
    name: string
}

function createA() {
    return { name: "", bla: "" }
}

const a:A = createA() // ok

const b:A = { name: "", bla: "" } // error

function createA_(): A {
    return { name: "", bla: "" } // error
}
```

The 2 errors are:

> Type '{ name: string; bla: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bla' does not exist in type 'A'.(2322)

Is there a way to get the same error with the line `const a:A = createA()` with some kind of inferred returned type?

The documentation on [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) isn't very clear about that and doesn't even speak about object literal errors.

**EDIT**

Here is a more complex example:

```
interface AnySchema<T> {
    required(): AnySchema<T>
}

class ObjectSchema<T> implements AnySchema<T> {
    required() {
        return this
    }
    ignored() {
        return this
    }
}

class StringSchema implements AnySchema<string> {
    required() {
        return this
    }
}

class Val {
    static object<T extends object>(spec: { [P in keyof T]: AnySchema<T[P]> }): ObjectSchema<T> {
        return new ObjectSchema<T>()
    }
    static string() {
        return new StringSchema()
    }
}

// ----

interface Coded {
    code: string
}

interface Named {
    name: string
    coded: Coded
}

// Now, here is a chunk of code with the issue shown in my first example:

const valSchema = Val.object<Named>({
    bla: Val.string(), // error
    name: Val.string(),
    coded: Val.object({
        bla: Val.string(), // ok
        code: Val.string()
    })
})

// But:

const valSchema = Val.object<Named>({
    bla: Val.string(), // error
    name: Val.string(),
    coded: Val.object<Coded>({ // <----- explicit typing
        bla: Val.string(), // error
        code: Val.string()
    })
})
```

So, again, is there a way to enforce *excess property checks* (see @jonrsharpe comment) without explicitly typing the second `Val.object` call?

I'm aware TypeScript is [*structurally typed*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) and I believe that what I ask for isn't possible. But I want to be sure there is no way to achieve *excess property checks* in this case (which is just a more complex example of excess property checks of object literals).

Comment: You're describing _excess property checks_, and no. You can only access `name` through `A` anyway. And frankly you should always declare return types explicitly so the compiler can _check_ them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe _excess property checks_ does work with object literals. My code above is the simplest I have found to show the problem. I'm not, of course, writing this kind of code and I'm going to add a more complex snippet to my question.

Comment: Yes, I know it works with object literals, that's what you're showing in your second and third examples. But in the first you're splitting it into two steps: 1. the compiler has to infer the return type (`{ name: string; bla: string; }`); _then_ 2. decide if that's assignable to `A` (which it **is** - TypeScript is _structurally_ typed). You already have a solution: make the return type explicit, so excess property checks can be applied to the return value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to define an interface/type to which excess property checks are always applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929016/is-it-possible-to-define-an-interface-type-to-which-excess-property-checks-are-a)